# This Python quiz is driving me crazy

Tags: python

I'm new to StackOverflow (1st time posting) and new to coding with python. Currently enrolled in a course through Udacity. I'm having a very hard time with a project we were given for this course and decided to come here to see if anyone could help.

The project is to create a quiz with 4 blanks that need to be answered correctly by the player. It's required to have the quiz print out with the correct answer, but I'm having a very hard time getting this to print out correctly.

My code is below. Would appreciate any help or advice I can get on this.

Thanks!

```
    easy_quiz = "If you ever get stuck, check out the __1__ for common 
    problems students face when attempting this project. If you need 
    additional help, you can schedule a 1:1 appointment with one of our 
    __2__ to get you un-stuck. This project should be __3__. If at any time 
    it becomes not fun, take a step back, deep breath, and ask for __4__!. 
    \n\n"
    easy_answers = ["forums", "mentors", "fun", "help"]

    medium_quiz = "Game must have 3 or more levels and each level contains 4 or more __1__ to fill in. Immediately after running the program, user is prompted to select a difficulty level from easy / __2__ / hard. Once a level is selected, game displays a fill-in-the-blank and a prompt to fill in the first one. When player guesses __3__, new prompt shows with correct answer in the previous blank and a new prompt for the next blank. When player guesses __4__, they are prompted to try again. \n"
medium_answers = ["blanks", "medium", "correctly", "incorrectly"]

hard_quiz = "__1__ are used as __2__ to automate tasks which are likely to be repeated. Functions produce the appropriate output (typically with a __3__ statement) from the appropriate input (function parameters). Your code should take advantage of __4__ and variable names should reflect the values they store. \n"  
hard_answers = ["Functions", "tools", "return", "variables"]

blanks = ["__1__", "__2__", "__3__", "__4__"]

difficulty = raw_input("\nChoose your difficuty level = easy, medium, or hard? ")
print "" 
if difficulty == "easy":
    quiz = easy_quiz
    answers = easy_answers
    print "You chose easy!\n\nYou will have 5 guesses to fill in each blank. Good Luck!!\n \n" + easy_quiz

elif difficulty == "medium":
    quiz = medium_quiz
    answers = medium_answers
    print "You chose medium!\n\nYou will have 5 guesses to fill in each blank. Good Luck!!\n \n" + medium_quiz

elif difficulty == "hard":
    quiz = hard_quiz
    answers = hard_answers
    print "You chose hard!\n\nYou will have 5 guesses to fill in each blank. Good Luck!!\n \n" + hard_quiz

def word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech):
    for pos in parts_of_speech:
        if pos in word:
            return pos
    return None

def play_game(quiz, parts_of_speech): 
    replaced = []
    i = 0
    quiz = quiz.split() 
    for word in quiz:
        replacement = word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech)
        if replacement != None:
            user_input = raw_input("Type an answer for: " + replacement + " " )
            word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
            replaced.append(word)
            guesses = 0
            while user_input != answers[i]:
                guesses = guesses + 1 
                print "Incorrect, try again \n" + " ".join(replaced)
                user_input = raw_input("Type an answer for: " + replacement + " ")
                if guesses == 4:
                    return "\nGame Over! Better luck next time. \n"
            print "Correct \n" + " ".join(replaced)
            i = i + 1 
            word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
            replaced.append(word)
        else:
            replaced.append(word)
    replaced = " ".join(replaced)
    return replaced

print play_game(quiz, blanks)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: You haven't described a particular problem, so there's not much we can (or should) do to help you under Stack Overflow's charter.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.    We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Also, have you done your expected research?  Various problems with this assignment have been posted to SO and other supportive sites.  If you have a new problem of general interest, please describe and demonstrate it for us.

Comment: If you run the code in python and play the game, you'd be able to see the problem i'm having. When the correct answer is entered by the player, the quiz needs to 'print' the quiz with the correct answer filled in for the blank.

Comment: @fredcoremusic People tend to dislike needing to copy your code into a file and start figuring out the problem description by themselves when you could just describe what is supposed to happen and what happens instead. Many of us answer questions here even without having access to a Python interpreter at all times, so executing your code is often times not even an option. Please update your post with a problem description that doesn't require everyone to run your code.

Comment: @bgse Understood! Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version of your play_game() method:

```
def play_game(quiz, parts_of_speech):
    replaced = []
    i = 0
    quiz = quiz.split()
    for word in quiz:
        replacement = word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech)
        if replacement is not None:
            user_input = raw_input("Type an answer for: " + replacement + " " )
            guesses = 0
            while user_input != answers[i]:
                guesses = guesses + 1
                if guesses == 5:
                    return "\nGame Over! Better luck next time. \n"
                print "Incorrect, try again \n" + " ".join(replaced) + " " + replacement
                user_input = raw_input("Type an answer for: " + replacement + " ")
            replaced.append(user_input)
            print "Correct \n" + " ".join(replaced)
            i = i + 1
        else:
            replaced.append(word)
    replaced = " ".join(replaced)
    return replaced
```

The main change is to delay modifying the `replaced` list until the correct answer has been given. That simplifies a lot of the code, eliminating the need for the `word` variable.